# What's the difference between the fishing poles?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

You start out with the Teacher's Pole, and I see that one of the rewards offered by the Fisherman who teaches you to fish is the Old Man's Pole. What's the difference between the poles offered in the game? Does the cursor for catching them move slower? Is the Impact area larger or does it do more damage? Do I get more chances to successfully catch the fish?

Basically, what advantages does the Old Man's Pole have over the Teacher's Pole (or any other, if there are hidden ones)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of newer fishing poles is that it reduces the speed of the cursor. Some of the fiestier fish, like *Axolotls*, have an extremely high speed *and* a tiny hit zone, so the better rods are almost necessary. And, of course, for all others it also makes the job a lot easier. The impact zone and the damage rate do not change.

There are some distinct differences between them, however. Certain fish will not respond to you using specific poles. One example is, the biggest of fish will *not* bite if you are using the Old Man Pole. This includes *Oarfish*, *Mecha-Coelecanths*, and *"Sperm Whales"*. You will need to use a different fishing pole in order to catch these. As such, pay attention - if the fish just isn't coming around even when all the other fish have tried, that means that the fish isn't going to respond to your current pole of choice.